# Dependence of the magneto-rotational instability (MRI) on thermal relaxation?

Tags: thermodynamics, turbulence, magnetohydrodynamics, accretion-disk

The [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorotational_instability) is the most efficient driver of turbulence in accretion discs (as measured by the effective scalar stress). The magnetic field, being properly coupled to the gas (weak coupling), connects the fluid elements with different angular momentum. The "communication" in a shearing flow allows the angular momentum redistribution and accretion.

I guess, because the process does not include any thermal effects (e.g., compression-induced heating or buoyancy), it is not sensitive to the thermal relaxation of the fluid. 
But does this hold true in case the coupling is due to collisional thermal ionization?

Comment: Do you mean by "thermal ionization" that there is a source of charged particles within the system, thus a time varying density/flux?  If so, then you will be changing the parameters of the system (e.g., Alfvén speed), which might influence some of the terms in the instability.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I mean collisional ionization provided by high enough temperatures via Boltzmann-Saha equilibrium.